# POST raw json data to server : AngularJS, Ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, raw-data

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/4961d6259eff467838fb

I'm getting post success in jQuery ajax. But not working the same in Angular http post.

```
$http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: 'http://sysdatacenter.com/WS/DataService.svc/Customer',
                        data: '[{"AddressArabic":"fgdfgdfg","AddressEnglish":"fw4534sdv","BusinessCategoryID":3,"CityID":3,"Comments":null,"CompanyName":"rwerwer","CompanyNameArabic":"ssdfgdfgd","ContactNo":3534535,"ContactPerson":"sdfsdfsd","CreatedBy":"admin","CreatedDate":"06-10-2016 12:19:25","CustomerCode":"werw","CustomerID":1,"DeviceTaskID":null,"Email":"rwerwrw@sfsdf.dgd","Fax":3453453,"Flexfld1":null,"Flexfld2":null,"Flexfld3":null,"Flexfld4":null,"Flexfld5":null,"IsActive":1,"IsSync":1,"ModifiedBy":"admin","ModifiedDate":"06-10-2016 12:19:25","POBox":345,"TradeLicenseNo":"erwe","TradeLicenseNoArabic":"gdfgdfgd","TransactionType":"I"},{"AddressArabic":"fgdfgdfg","AddressEnglish":"fw4534sdv","BusinessCategoryID":3,"CityID":3,"Comments":null,"CompanyName":"rwerwer","CompanyNameArabic":"ssdfgdfgd","ContactNo":3534535,"ContactPerson":"sdfsdfsd","CreatedBy":"admin","CreatedDate":"06-10-2016 12:19:25","CustomerCode":"werw","CustomerID":1,"DeviceTaskID":null,"Email":"rwerwrw@sfsdf.dgd","Fax":3453453,"Flexfld1":null,"Flexfld2":null,"Flexfld3":null,"Flexfld4":null,"Flexfld5":null,"IsActive":1,"IsSync":1,"ModifiedBy":"admin","ModifiedDate":"06-10-2016 12:19:25","POBox":345,"TradeLicenseNo":"erwe","TradeLicenseNoArabic":"gdfgdfgd","TransactionType":"I"}]',
                        headers: {"deviceid":"ABC1234"}
                    }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(r)

                    }, function (err) {


                        });
```

Comment: i tryed you data in post man it is not working it says end point not found so you have to check your json string

Comment: Make sure this is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuraj910/zx04ebhv/

Comment: Can you please check there is raw data.
Thank you

Comment: send me working json and posting object for demo which works in postman your problem is your Json string and your object that your posting to that json

Comment: The one shared postman is working here. It'll give 0 response which is a success

Comment: Added method name in url. Please check now

Comment: i see that send the posting object not the url formate of the posting object like you have given in data field in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114336/discussion-between-vishnuraj-and-mohan-gopi).